# IFormFile returns null value on dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, postman

I have a post request for my PhotosController class. When I test this code, it always returns a null value. I don't see file details. Basically it gets the userid and PhotoDto and it should return photo. I use Cloudinary service to store photos. My API settings of the clodinary is located inside appsettings.json file and there is no problem for those settings. When I debug the code, the problem occurs where if (file.Length > 0) is. I am guessing that there is no file.

PhotoForCreationDto file:

[image]

PhotosController file:

[image]

Postman Error:
Body,

[image]

Header,

[image]

Comment: Thanks.... Its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postman, you are saying the `content-type` is `application/json`. It's not. Remove that line from Postman. Postman will automatically fill in the appropriate `content-type` based on your "body" data.